# how to mutating kubernetes resource 'bindings' with mutating webhook

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to mutating resource 'bindings' which is from kube-scheduler in common case.
Following is my 'ValidatingWebhookConfiguration' yaml:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
name: validation-webhook-cfg
labels:
 app: k8sfed-webhook
webhooks:
- name: required-labels.kubefed.webhook.com
 clientConfig:
   service:
     name: k8sfed-webhook-svc
     namespace: default
     path: "/validate"
   caBundle: xxxxx==
 rules:
   - operations: [ "CREATE" ]
     apiGroups: ["apps", ""]
     apiVersions: ["v1"]
     resources: ["deployments","services", "bindings", "pods"]
 namespaceSelector:
   matchLabels:
     k8sfed-webhook: enabled
```

in my webhook service, create of deployments, services, and pods all can be caught but only 'bindings' is an exception.
If anybody have also met this case alike before, it would be greatly appreciated to offer some suggestions.

Comment: Try using `pods/binding` instead of `bindings`.

Comment: yes, it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in k8s github repo:  [Delete /binding](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/10043).

> We need to update the scheduler [...] to use pods/binding instead of /binding and then we can delete /binding.

And also [deprication of bindings](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/47041)

Because bindings are used during scheduling, you can check what permissions are used by scheduler.
Running `kubectl get clusterrole system:kube-scheduler -oyaml` you will see:

```
...
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - bindings
  - pods/binding
  verbs:
  - create
...
```

And this suggests that there are both: `bindings` and `pods/binding` being used (even though bindings is depricated). I will leave this decision to you, whether you want to use both or only the supported one.